# how to comparison between two date in android?

Tags: android, date, comparison

I want to Date comparison between Start Date and End Date. End Date is Greater than Start Date OR End Date is Equal to Start Date. How to possible? Its Comparison between only day. If I am enter Start Date is "15-12-2014" and End Date is "14-07-2015" then Its Not Accept. What is my Mistake? Please Guide me.
Thanks in Advance.

```
boolean b=false;


public boolean isDateAfter(String startDate, String endDate) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf;
            String myFormatString = "dd-mm-yyyy"; // for example
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormatString);
            endingDate = sdf.parse(endDate);
            startingDate = sdf.parse(startDate);
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!! startingDate===="+startingDate);
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!! endingDate====="+endingDate);
            if ((endingDate.after(startingDate))
                    || (endingDate.equals(startingDate)))
                b = true;
            else
                b = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            b = false;
        }
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: what is your start date and end date here?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use SimpleDateFormat, use Time stamp like:

```
Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
```

Comment: Have you any demo then send me please

Answer (score 0):

You may rely on the built-in methods like `date.after()` or `date.before()` for comparison.

For more control, you may also convert your date into `long` value by using `date.getTime()` and perform further calculations.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the built in methods date.after,date.before and date.equals to do this easily

Comment: I am using Build in function but it comparison between day. see updated Question plz.